# Как скрыть информацию в NSLog?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Каждый раз, когда вывожу что-либо через функцию NSLog(), перед моим сообщением добавляется служебная информация.
Например:

> 2013-11-30 23:09:10.003 TimeAfterTime[47507:303]

Можно ли как-то её убрать?

Пока придумал вот что:
Функция:

```
void trace (NSString *obj)
{
    printf("%s\n", [[obj description] UTF8String]);
}
```

Вызов функции:

```
trace([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %@, %@", [now timeIntervalSince1970], string1, string2]);
```

Но вводить каждый раз **[NSString stringWithFormat:** долго. Можно это как-то в функцию запихнуть?

Comment: Вы можете использовать `printf` или `cout`.

Comment: Запись
> printf("%@",[NSDate date]);  //Invalid conversion specifier '@'
некорректна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я в своё время писал что-то подобное:

```
/**
 * «Quiet» log
 */
void QLog(NSString *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    NSString *tmp = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: format arguments: args];
    va_end(args);
    printf("%s\n", [tmp UTF8String]);
    [tmp release];
}
```

Использовать точно так же, как и `NSLog()`:

```
QLog(@"Name is %@", person.name);
```

Comment: Закоментил строку [tmp release];  
Ну и в person.name]  ']' - лишняя

Comment: @samoilow действительно, скобку зачем-то поставил, спасибо.  
Ну а насчёт `-release` — понятно, что при ARC он не нужен.

Answer (score 3):

printf() Сишная функция, ей нужно помочь работать с obj-c объектами:

```
printf("%s", [[[NSDate date] description] UTF8String]);
```

Comment: ну и `\n` в конце